# Python - Pandas dataframe concatenation Balloons in memory

Tags: python, pandas, sparse-matrix

My original dataset is a large list of JSON objects for an adverse reaction to a drug(s). In each JSON object we can have several drugs that give an adverse reaction in the form of rxcui ids.

I have taken the list of JSON objects and extracted the important data we need such as if the person died, and the rxcui and flattened them to a JSON object that is at max 2 levels deep. We would have something like this:

```
{
  "serious": 1,
  "drug": [
    "DrugA",
    "DrugB",
    "DrugC"
  ],
  "rxcui": [
    100,
    200,
    300
  ]
}
```

As we can I have to figure out how I can make this in to an array I can feed to a ML algorithm. So My idea is to use one-hot encoding.

This is why I am using the countVectorizer so I can vectorize all of these sub lists

I am trying to concatenate several pandas dataframes (some are sparse dataframes and some are regular) which are onehot encodings of some data. I have checked all of the files (I also pickled them on to the hard disk) and none are larger than 81MB. But as soon as I start to concatenating them they blowup to over 29 GB. How is that possible?

All of my df look like this:

```
Label0  Label1  Label2  Label3...  Label999
1       1       0       0     ...  0
1       1       0       1     ...  1
.
.
.
```

I run concat like this:

```
x = pandas.concat([x, drugcharacterization, occurcountry, reactionmeddrapt, reactionmeddraversionpt, reactionoutcome, rxcui],axis=1, copy=False)
```

I can also fit all of the sub dataframes I am trying to concatenate easily in memory. Any reason why it blows up once I do this?

**edit:**
Here is how I am getting my dataframes. As we can see I cant create a sparse matrix of one of them, it gives me an error:

> ```
> raise ValueError("empty vocabulary; perhaps the documents only contain stop words")
> ```

```
import pandas
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer    
rr = pandas.DataFrame()
for col in categorical_labels:
    print col
    try:
        vect = CountVectorizer()
        X = vect.fit_transform(z[col].astype(str).map(lambda x: ' '.join(x) if isinstance(x, list) else x))
        r = pandas.SparseDataFrame(X, columns=vect.get_feature_names(), index=z.index, default_fill_value=0).add_prefix(col + ' = ')
        r.to_pickle(col + '_subarr.pkl')
    except:
        r = z[col].astype(str).str.strip('[]').str.get_dummies(', ').add_prefix(col + ' = ')
        r.to_pickle(col + '_subarr.pkl')

    rr = pandas.concat([rr,r], axis=1)
```

**and here are their indecies:**

```
drugcharacterization.index
Out[13]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=234372, step=1)

occurcountry.index
Out[14]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=234372, step=1)

reactionmeddrapt.index
Out[15]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=234372, step=1)

reactionmeddraversionpt.index
Out[16]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=234372, step=1)

reactionoutcome.index
Out[17]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=234372, step=1)

rxcui.index
Out[18]: RangeIndex(start=0, stop=234372, step=1)
```

Comment: what is your Pandas version?

Comment: This is bit unusal usage of CountVectorizer... What is `categorical_labels`?

Comment: @MaxU the categorical labels are the labels that are categories. My data is mixed, some columns are numerical, some are categories, some are lists of numbers, and some are categories in a list: such as the column drug and in each cell would be a list of drugs

Comment: I don't understand why are you calling `CounterVectorizer` and `vect.fit_transform` multiple times in loop...

Comment: @MaxU sorry this should not be there it was a programming error. I just had to get the code out quick.

Comment: if all DF's that you want to ncatenate are SparseDataFrames (or at least have only supported for sparse matrixes dtypes) - you can use  `sparse.hstack()` method - see example in my answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

AFAIK `pd.concat([...])` generates a new **regular** (not sparsed) DataFrame.

Consider the following example (I used Pandas **0.20.1**):

source DFs:

```
In [118]: df
Out[118]:
                                                text
0  With free-text, each letter is actually an ind...
1                As far as the computer is concerned
2  no individual letter or number has any relatio...

In [119]: another
Out[119]:
    a   b   c
0  10  23  87
1  12  45  32
2  14  76  89
```

Let's one-hot-encode the text:

```
from sklearn.feature_extraction.text import CountVectorizer

vect = CountVectorizer(stop_words='english')

# one-hot-encoded
# for Pandas version < 0.20.1 use: vect.fit_transform(df.text).A
ohe = pd.SparseDataFrame(vect.fit_transform(df.text),
                         columns=vect.get_feature_names(),
                         index=df.index,
                         default_fill_value=0)
```

Result - SparseDataFrame (pay attention at memory usage):

```
In [127]: ohe
Out[127]:
   actually  computer  concerned  far  free  independent  individual  letter  number  object  relationship  text
0         1         0          0    0     1            1           0       1       0       1             0     1
1         0         1          1    1     0            0           0       0       0       0             0     0
2         0         0          0    0     0            0           1       2       2       0             1     0

In [128]: ohe.memory_usage()
Out[128]:
Index           80
actually         8
computer         8
concerned        8
far              8
free             8
independent      8
individual       8
letter          16
number           8
object           8
relationship     8
text             8
dtype: int64
```

let's concatenate this SparseDataFrame with source DFs (regular ones):

```
In [129]: r = pd.concat([another, df, ohe], axis=1)

In [130]: r
Out[130]:
    a   b   c                                               text  actually  computer  concerned  far  free  independent  individual  \
0  10  23  87  With free-text, each letter is actually an ind...         1         0          0    0     1            1           0
1  12  45  32                As far as the computer is concerned         0         1          1    1     0            0           0
2  14  76  89  no individual letter or number has any relatio...         0         0          0    0     0            0           1

   letter  number  object  relationship  text
0       1       0       1             0     1
1       0       0       0             0     0
2       2       2       0             1     0

In [131]: r.memory_usage()
Out[131]:
Index           80
a               24
b               24
c               24
text            24
actually        24
computer        24
concerned       24
far             24
free            24
independent     24
individual      24
letter          24
number          24
object          24
relationship    24
text            24
dtype: int64
```

**NOTE:** `pd.concat()` has created a new regular DataFrame, so all "sparsed" columns got densed...

for purely numeric SparseDataFrames or SparseArrays we can use [scipy.sparse.hstack([...])](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.hstack.html):

```
In [149]: from scipy import sparse

In [150]: r = pd.SparseDataFrame(sparse.hstack([ohe, another]), 
                                 columns=ohe.columns.append(another.columns))

In [151]: r.memory_usage()
Out[151]:
Index           80
actually         8
computer         8
concerned        8
far              8
free             8
independent      8
individual       8
letter          16
number           8
object           8
relationship     8
text             8
a               24
b               24
c               24
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Ah, this could be why

Comment: So lets say I want to concatenate these sparse dataframes with one data frame that isnt sparse the correct way is to use the hstack?

Comment: @Kevin, it'll work only for supported (for sparsed matrixes) dtypes. Are you sure you need to concatenate sparsed data with regular DF? If it's absolutely necessarry you can add columns from regular DF to SparseDataFrame one-by-one in a loop - this should not explode sparsed columns to dense

Comment: ah interesting, The only reason I am doing this is is because some of my data is not one hot encoded. they are just numbers. I guess I could just convert that other dataframe into a sparse df

Comment: `sparse.hstack([...])` should work for regular DFs if they have `int64` columns

Answer (score 2):

I suspect your dataframes do not share indices, and thus you're building a much larger dataframe than you anticipate.

For example, consider the following:

```
df1 = pd.DataFrame({'x': [1, 2, 3]}, index=[0, 1, 2])
df2 = pd.DataFrame({'y': [2, 4, 6]}, index=[3, 4, 5])

print(pd.concat([df1, df2], axis=1))
     x    y
0  1.0  NaN
1  2.0  NaN
2  3.0  NaN
3  NaN  2.0
4  NaN  4.0
5  NaN  6.0
```

Here we are joining two dataframes, and the result is 4x as large as the inputs because the indices are not shared. For your 7 dataframes, it's possible to have a concatenated result that is ~50x larger than the size of the inputs if none of the indices are shared.

Without more information I can't be certain that's what's happening in your case, but that is where I would start investigating.

Comment: I have added what my indices are